# Pushing to secured docker registry gets 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: ssl, docker, nginx, docker-registry

I followed [this](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/how-to-secure-your-private-docker-registry/) link to create a dockerized proxy server for my registry.
I ran these commands:

```
htpasswd -c ~/my-registry.htpasswd USERNAME
mkdir ~/certs
docker run --rm  -e COMMON_NAME=hostName -e KEY_NAME=my-registry -v ~/certs:/certs centurylink/openssl
docker run -d --expose=5000 --name=registry registry:2
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e PUBLIC_IP_ADDR=hostName --link registry:registry -v ~/certs/my-registry.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/docker-registry -v ~/certs/my-registry.key:/etc/ssl/private/docker-registry -v ~/my-registry.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/docker-registry.htpasswd centurylinklabs/nginx-ssl-proxy
```

I then opened the https://hostName:8080/v2/ in my browser, exported the certificate, and installed the `crt` file on my windows client, and also saved a copy to `C:\ProgramData\Docker\certs.d\hostName8080\ca.crt`

The login to registry is completely successful, but when I run

```
docker push hostName:8080/base
```

The following response is returned:

```
90c0b5c927ee: Pushing [==================================================>]  316.4kB
48a81194835d: Pushing [==================================================>]  2.048kB
024e3f43ffc2: Pushing [==================================================>]  8.382MB/8.382MB
error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>\r\n<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.7.9</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

And the image isn't uploaded.

This is the docker logs of the push:

```
"GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 194 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"POST /v2/base/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"POST /v2/base/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"POST /v2/base/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"PATCH /v2/base/blobs/uploads/65e201c4-66b9-4723-a074-7fdcc8535665?_state=H4ygF8XuJkl24AWQeN19_7fgpAiyDeNlWnwbmPdZ8Tl7Ik5hbWUiOiJiYXNlIiwiVVVJRCI6IjY1ZTIwMWM0LTY2YjktNDcyMy1hMDc0LTdmZGNjODUzNTY2NSIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAxOC0wMS0yMVQwNTo1MToxNy4yMzg0OTIwMjZaIn0%3D HTTP/1.1" 400 270 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"PATCH /v2/base/blobs/uploads/a431532f-a2dc-4ac4-aea3-67b62594a57e?_state=D2FM5ALYWtMF1xotyibSEmHyAH6pdJJXWXZFpqWR2hl7Ik5hbWUiOiJiYXNlIiwiVVVJRCI6ImE0MzE1MzJmLWEyZGMtNGFjNC1hZWEzLTY3YjYyNTk0YTU3ZSIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAxOC0wMS0yMVQwNTo1MToxNy4yMjk5ODQwNDNaIn0%3D HTTP/1.1" 400 270 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
"PATCH /v2/base/blobs/uploads/7868c561-5524-4c32-8d2a-c2121e54fb00?_state=i4KyRqAo_LI3S6ED7j9sC7EQbLwAWpXLnWXlQuPf2yR7Ik5hbWUiOiJiYXNlIiwiVVVJRCI6Ijc4NjhjNTYxLTU1MjQtNGMzMi04ZDJhLWMyMTIxZTU0ZmIwMCIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAxOC0wMS0yMVQwNTo1MToxNy4yMjk0ODIyMjZaIn0%3D HTTP/1.1" 400 270 "-" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \x5C(windows\x5C))" "-"
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163566/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-mohsen).